# Tableau Angular2 Integration

Tags: angular, tableau-api

Has anyone tried building an Angular2 application with tableau visualizations integrated in it using the [Tableau JavaScript API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm)?

According to the documentation, you're supposed to include the following script in your file which will create a `tableau` global variable: 
`<script src="https://YOUR-SERVER/javascripts/api/tableau-2.js"></script>`

I'm not sure how to access this global variable within an Angular2 class.

Comment: Assuming it actually creates a global `tableau` reference, the reference should be available to any script at any time. Just start using it: `var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url);`.

Answer (score 1):

Im using ng2-admin template and I was able to successfully integrate Tableau and Angular2.

Copy this script `<script src="https://YOUR-SERVER/javascripts/api/tableau-2.js"></script>` in index.html and paste it within its `<body>`. Then copy the embed code in any of the components html file within a div.

Answer (score 1):

```js
declare var tableau: any;

viz: any;//Inside your component class


initViz() {
    const containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer");
    const vizUrl="https://public.tableau.com/views/WorldIndicators/GDPpercapita";
 
    const options = {
      width: containerDiv.offsetWidth,
      height: 600,
      // hideTabs: true,
      // hideToolbar: true,
      onFirstInteractive: function (ev) {
        console.log(ev);
      }
    };
    if(viz != null) { // viz is undefined on both the first and second page loads - even though second page load throws a 'viz already present' error
     viz.dispose();
    }
    var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, vizUrl,options);
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {    
    this.initViz();
  }
```

By declaring global variable you can acces it inside component.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to embed Tableau visualizations in Angular apps, **[ngx-tableau](https://github.com/nfqsolutions/ngx-tableau)** provides a simple interface to the Tableau JavaScript API.

It has multiple options for configuring the connection to Tableau Server, handling authentication tickets, adding filters to reports, and managing different sites.

Disclaimer: I am the main contributor to the library.

Comment: Is it for custom tableau servers or only for public urls? I wonder because on npm page it says "public" APIs. We will probably use it next project if it doesn't have to be public API.

Comment: @firstChild the most basic example uses a public Tableau visualization, but it can be used with private visualizations. In fact, the module was created to embed private visualizations through the different [Configuration options](https://github.com/nfqsolutions/ngx-tableau#configuration-options)

Comment: Ok thanks. I can't find license information on github, can you maybe add it? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for raising this issue @firstChild, the MIT LICENSE file was included in the module, but not included in the root of the repository, so GitHub didn't show it. It is fixed now.